# how to initialize final variable boolean array in method void

Tags: android, android-studio, boolean

my application will check whether the play protect settings are activated or not.

```
public static boolean checkGooglePlayProtectSettings(Context context){
    final boolean[] enabled = new boolean[]{false};
    try{
        SafetyNet.getClient(context).isVerifyAppsEnabled().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<SafetyNetApi.VerifyAppsUserResponse>() {

            @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<SafetyNetApi.VerifyAppsUserResponse> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            SafetyNetApi.VerifyAppsUserResponse result = task.getResult();
                            if(result != null){
                                if(result.isVerifyAppsEnabled()){
                                    enabled[0] = true;
                                }else{
                                    enabled[0] = false;

                                }
                            }
                        }else{
                            Log.e("GoogleProtectPermission", "A general error occurred.");
                        }
                    }
                });
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (enabled[0]){
        Log.d("GoogleProtectPermission", "Is enabled");
    }else {
        Log.d("GoogleProtectPermission", "Is disabled");
    }
    return false;
}
```

in this case I tried the final results to log, but always not active in the log results, how to get good results to check whether play prtoect is active or not?

Answer (score 0):

The `isVerifyAppsEnabled()` method is asynchronous, it calls the `OnCompleteListener`'s `onComplete` method to notify when the result is ready.

It's likely that this block is executed before the `OnCompleteListener` is fired, so the `enabled[0]` value remains the same at this point.

```
if (enabled[0]) {
    Log.d("GoogleProtectPermission", "Is enabled");
} else {
    Log.d("GoogleProtectPermission", "Is disabled");
}
```

Since there's no synchronous method to get the result, you'll probably have to change your approach someway to take account for this asynchronicity and perform dependent operations when the callback results are ready or perform a blocking wait until the `Task` returned by `isVerifyAppsEnabled` is completed.

Also, disregarding the question, in your current code there seems to be little point in using boolean array instead of just a boolean for this, and this

```
if(result.isVerifyAppsEnabled()) {
    enabled[0] = true;
} else {
    enabled[0] = false;
}
```

can be simplified to this `enabled[0] = result.isVerifyAppsEnabled()`

Answer (score -2):

You could do like this:

```
final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
...
if(result.isVerifyAppsEnabled()){
    sb.append("good");
}else{
    sb.append("bad");
}
...
if(sb.toString().equals("good")){
    Log.d("GoogleProtectPermission", "Is enabled");
}
if(sb.toString().equals("bad")){
    Log.d("GoogleProtectPermission", "Is disabled");
}
```

**Edited:**
   Yes, as comment points, My answer is wrong. so there are two ways:

1 directly output log info

```
   if(result.isVerifyAppsEnabled()){
       Log.d("GoogleProtectPermission", "Is enabled");
    }else{
        Log.d("GoogleProtectPermission", "Is disabled");
    }
```

2 using interface callback

```
   public interface Callback {  //add an interface 
        void onResponse(String message);
    }

    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    ...
    if(result.isVerifyAppsEnabled()){
        sb.append("good");
    }else{
        sb.append("bad");
    }
    callback.onResponse(sb.toString()); //add this line
```

and subscribe the interface in some place.

Comment: That won't work due to asynchronous nature of the `isVerifyAppsEnabled()` method. And using `String`s and `StringBuilder`s instead of `boolean` values is a [bad practice](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/365344), it creates a lot of unnecessary objects, performs a lot of unneeded operations, lacks type safety and compile checks and **it** **shouldn't** **be** **done** **at** **all**. There is, in fact a term for this - [Stringly Typed](http://wiki.c2.com/?StringlyTyped).

Comment: @MikhailOlshanski yes, you are right, I modify answer, thank you!